# PIC16f628a internal oscillator runs at a lower frequency than expected

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, pic16f

Specifically speaking, it runs at almost exactly 1 MHz instead of the supposed 4 supplied by the internal oscillator. This is probably the cause of other strange behaviour like failing to blink an LED at 1 Hz (described in the code below) blinking it at precisely 50 Hz, according to my multimeter. Below is the code and schematic of the circuit.

main.c

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define LED_1 RA0
#define LED_2 RA7

/*
void __interrupt() isr(void){
    
    if(INTCONbits.INTF && INTCONbits.INTE){

        INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
        TRISAbits.TRISA7 = 0;
            
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            PORTAbits.LED_2 = 1;
            __delay_ms(500);
            PORTAbits.LED_2 = 0;
            __delay_ms(200);
            }        
    }
}
*/

void main(void) {
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0;
    
    OPTION_REGbits.INTEDG = 1;
    INTCON = 0xF8;
    
    while(1){
        PORTAbits.RA0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
        PORTAbits.RA0 = 0;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

conbits.h

```
// more than once.  
#ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
#define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H

#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCCLK // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: CLKOUT function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has PGM function, low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h> // include processor files - each processor file is guarded.  



#endif  /* XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H */
```

[image: the schematic]

The MCU worked fine before and I have no clue what could've caused it. I had noticed some strange behaviour though, when plugging in something external like an oscilloscope or a multimeter (which was more reliable for some reason than the latter) the pic would do something very similar, although i didn't think much of it then and therefore, haven't measured this state until now. I am also going to try and use some low-frequency external oscillator, like an ne555 to see if the problem is just the internal osc or something deeper. For additional context, I'm using a K150 and microbrn to flash the hex file but I don't think it matters since it hasn't caused any issues, as far as I know.

Comment: I forgot to add the schematic so here's an imgur link to it: https://imgur.com/Xpqq3QF

Comment: Are you considering the fact that each CPU instruction cycle takes 4 clock cycles?

Comment: Add 100 nF capacitors either side of the regulator. It may be oscillating and continually restarting the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the interrupt, the `INTCON` register should've been 0 on the most significant bit (the global interrupt enable). Due to interrupts being a thing, and the INT not being grounded, the chip would trigger interrupts and without an isr (which i commented out for testing just the blinking) it would just get stuck (flags weren't resetting making it lock up).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken how the PIC works. It takes 4 clock cycles to execute a single machine instruction cycle.

So at 4 MHz clock it will execute 1 MHz worth of opcodes.

Also since you are enabling the CLKOUT functionality, it will also output the 4 MHz oscillator divided by 4, so measuring with an oscilloscope will give you 1 MHz.

Comment: Well that's helpful but even after adding the 2 caps, as the comments suggested, the operation is still unreliable. This time though the led flashes as it should like 3 or 4 times every time i let the input cap discharge, then it just goes into this peculiar 50hz state.

Comment: Maybe you have watchdog enabled. You have selected the watchdog disabled in the CONFIG bits, but did you actually program the CONFIG bits to the MCU? Be careful not to select incorrect settings, as you might disable reset pin, change the oscillator setting to something you don't have, or disable further programming with the programmer you have.

Answer (score 0):

Most pics have a clock divisor.  I don't see that being explicitly set in your code, maybe it defaults to 4, or is set elsewhere?